# Mutiple ReactDOM.render functions?

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting to learn react and getting a problem when calling multiple ReactDOM.render functions:

react:

```
class Header extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
       <p>Test1</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

class Main extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <section>
        <p>Test2</p>
      </section>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root2'));
ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

html part:

```
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div id="root2"></div>
</body>
```

I'm getting the error:

Target container is not a DOM element.

When searching for this problem I got the information that it should be possible to call ReactDom.render multiple times. So I appreciate your help!

Edit: Just tried it with one html tag and changed the id. It seems to have a problem when the id is not "root"...

Comment: your code working good https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-3pko9 .I thing you  are missing the react import on top

Comment: @prasanth Well, but not in my build. Is there something I have to config to get this working? I used "npm create reactapp".

Comment: you got this error https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-4bjd5 .Missing `root2` element in index.html .so you need to add `root2` id in index.html

Comment: @prasanth Yea, exactly. But i dont know why.

Comment: Missing `root2` element in index.html .so you need to add `root2` id in index.html or else follow the below answer.Better follow below answer most of the people used that way of single element render to html

Comment: @prasanth The root2 element exitts. That's why I asked the question. It's just not detected..

Comment: if its not "detected" then inspect your browser and see if the element is actually there. You may have a cached version of the html file loading that is missing the element

Comment: @JohnRuddell It's not. But I got no idea what the problem could be. Should be done by just adding it in the html file.

Comment: well I just gave a reason as to what the problem could be

Comment: @JohnRuddell Deleting the cache didn't fix it sadly.

Comment: Did you right click on the page -> inspect -> elements tab. Check and see if the element is there? regardless, you should really consider the answer supplied as that is the better approach.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I already used the answer and it's working (just missed the return statement). But I'm wondering why other html elements except the "root" node aren't displayed. And for sure I used the development tool the look for it.

Comment: well considering it works from prasanth's answer its most likely that you have referencing the wrong file or forgot a simple thing. Probably best to double check every step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you should be able to call render multiple times in your code.

But instead of doing that why don't you do this:

```
Class App extends Component {
    render(){
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        <Main />
      </React.Fragment>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

This is easier, correct and performance superior.

I really see no reason as to why soomeone woudld need to put 2 different renderers on one page. Its just putting more strain on the browser for no reason and it will slow down your application.

Comment: Well, I'm just getting started with react. So thanks for the hint!
But when trying this is returning a Failed to compile error...

Comment: @temp try it again, i just fixed the syntax issue.

Comment: @JohnRuddell whats this fragment thing? I think he forgot to import the header and main components since i was just writing a template not an actual application.

Comment: ohh nvm i forgot to wrap the elements. Yeah i was writing this in a hurry (im on the bus)

Comment: yea, you have 2 children need to have just one. u can use fragment for that. short hand syntax is much nicer but sometimes not supported `<>...</>`

Comment: the solution is actually to clear the cache of the browser because npm does like to store some data for optimized loading of the local server, but i think this is a better way to handle this question, so for anyone who is inevitably going to say "this was not the question", just know that questions can be answered in many ways.

Comment: I would say even more so, partly why you are getting the upvotes is because of your recommendation. Good engineers should ask "why" when something doesn't make sense or is the wrong approach. Pointing out the correct way even if its not fixing the original attempt is what you should do! :)